# Consultar por numero, idade de um aluno

Tags: c, string

Estou fazendo um programa em que necessito consultar um aluno(estrutura) que tem idade,nome,genero,nºde processo do aluno. Consultar pelos seguintes paramateros em baixo, pôs só um pouco de codigo mas necessito dos 11 paramateros. O que pôs em if() está mal

```js
void consultar()
{
    puts("1 - Número");
    puts("2 - Nome");
    puts("3 - Língua");
    puts("4 - Almoço");
    puts("5 - Idade");
    puts("6 - Entre idade");
    puts("7 - A partir de uma idade");
    puts("8 - Todos os ativos");
    puts("9 - Por género");
    puts("10 - Todos");
    puts("11 - Parte do nome");
    puts("0 - Voltar");
} 
typedef struct escola
{
    int n_aluno;
    char nome[30],lingua[30],almoco[30];
    int gen, idade, ativo, temp_lingua, temp_almoco;
}aluno;
int a,cont,op,i,n,n3,p,n2,n4,n5,n6,ocultar,guardar,t_aluno=3;
    char str[30],c[30],gene,resp;
    aluno temp,al[30]={{1,"Nuno aguileira","Espanhol","Refeitório",1,16,1},{2,"João Almeida","Francês","Casa",1,15,2},
    {3,"Francisco rodrigo","Espanhol","Cafetaria",1,17,1}};

case 5:     
                                do
                                {
                                    system("cls");
                                    printf("\n\nQual a idade do aluno: ");
                                    scanf("%d",&n6);    
                                    if(n6==al[30].idade) 
                                    {
                                        printf("\n\nNúmero de processo: %d",al[n-1].n_aluno);
                                        printf("\nNome: %s",al[n-1].nome);
                                        printf("\nLíngua: %s",al[n-1].lingua);
                                        printf("\nAlmoço: %s",al[n-1].almoco);
                                        printf("\nGênero: %d",al[n-1].gen);
                                        printf("\nIdade: %d",al[n-1].idade);
                                        printf("\nAtivo: %d",al[n-1].ativo);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        printf("Aluno não existe");
                                        fflush(stdin);
                                        getchar();
                                    }
                                }
                                while(n6==temp.idade);
                                break;
                        case 6:
                                do
                                {
                                    system("cls");
                                    printf("\n\nQual a idade do aluno. Escolha entre 2 números: ");
                                    scanf("%d",&n6);    
                                    if(n6==al[30].idade) 
                                    {
                                        printf("\n\nNúmero de processo: %d",al[n-1].n_aluno);
                                        printf("\nNome: %s",al[n-1].nome);
                                        printf("\nLíngua: %s",al[n-1].lingua);
                                        printf("\nAlmoço: %s",al[n-1].almoco);
                                        printf("\nGênero: %d",al[n-1].gen);
                                        printf("\nIdade: %d",al[n-1].idade);
                                        printf("\nAtivo: %d",al[n-1].ativo);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        printf("Aluno não existe");
                                        fflush(stdin);
                                        getchar();
                                    }
                                }
                                while(n6==temp.idade);
                                break;  
                    }       
                }
                while(n<1 || n>t_aluno);
                break;//só um pouco do código
```

Comment: poste um programa completo, compilável.....

Answer (score -1):

Eu considerava usar um 'ciclo for' que percorresse todos os elementos da estrutura e quando encontrasse por exemplo o aluno com o mesmo numero de aluno q o user introduziu entao retornasse todos os valores pretendidos.

Cada 'case' de pesquisa de um diferente parametro iria usar um ciclo com a mesma ideia alterando o parametro de comparacao (numero, nome, lingua...)

Comment: Já consegui descobrir com um ciclo for e um if(). Obrigado pela sua atenção